# Text box showing value as 3.2543254E7.How to avoid it and show as 325432547 in struts

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts2 for my application. I entered value as 325432547. In Edit mode value shows as 3.2543254E7. In text box to avoid it?

```
<s:textfield name="lstVehicleAttendance(%{#attr.row_rowNum-1}).closingTime"
id="closingTime" maxlength="20" size="20" value="%{#attr.row.closingTime}">
</s:textfield>
```

Comment: Entered value where? Edit mode what? Text box what? How are you displaying this value? Where's your code?

Comment: need information which version you are using and i tested this code and its showing it perfectly.Show you jsp and what and how you are displaying your code

Comment: how you calculating `attr.row.closingTime`? there is no relation of struts2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to define following in `default properties`

```
format.number = {0,number,#0.0##}
```

And call `getText(...)` from `s:textfield`

```
<s:textfield key="orderItem.price" 
             value="%{getText('format.number',{'orderItem.price'})}" />
```

See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to the Struts2.Your question still needs a lot of inputs to decide what exactly is the issue.

1. How you calculating the number?
2. Where you displaying it?
3. What you mean by Edit mode?

I assume that the issue might be coming when you are dealing with double/floating number.A double number can only store a certain amount of significant digits (with a decimal dot somewhere).

for example if i run this simple program in my editor

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double val=999999999.999999d;
        System.out.println(val);

    }
```

Output is `9.99999999999999E8`
so either you need some sort of [NumberFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

else use Struts2 Number formatting facility as it will also use same Java's built-in formatting features
[formatting-dates-and-numbers](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html)